# ConvertAPI Conversion Failed with "Maximum Execution time ... exceeded"

Tags: php, pdf, docx, convertapi

I am using convert API to convert DOCX to PDF with Laravel (PHP) but I get error like this. What should I do? I try to searching about this error but I can't find anything.

```
for($i=0, $i<size; $i++){
    $result = ConvertApi::convert('pdf', ['File' => file($i).docx,], 'docx');
}
```

[image: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in file]

Comment: How big was the document you were trying to convert?

Comment: 54 kb, I loop the conversion for 10 documents. I've tried to convert this before a month ago and it's fine

Comment: Hrm.  What's your code?  To my understanding, if you have `@files = ['file1', 'file2', etc...]`, then this should work?  `$result = ConvertApi::convert('merge', ['Files' => $files], 'pdf');
$result->saveFiles('/tmp');`?

Comment: Also, to clarify, no images?  Those can appear as only a few bytes, because they are hyperlinked, etc..  But can take extra computational resources compared to text.

Comment: for($i=0, $i<size; $i++){$result = ConvertApi::convert('pdf', ['File' => file($i).docx,], 'docx');}

Comment: the docx have an image

Comment: How big is the image?  Like, file-size?  Maybe reduce the size and retest?  Maybe try removing the image altogether?  If the image is hyperlinked on a website, does your process have access to the internet?

Comment: I don't know how big the image size but the docx size is .around 54kb. I can't delete this image because I need it

Comment: I try a month ago its clearly fine with the same file, maybe the problem with convertapi server ?

Comment: "I can't delete this image because I need it" -- Can you delete it merely as a testing procedure to see if this is where your problem is?

Comment: okey, a few minutes ago I have tried to delete the images and the docx can converted, and then I tried to put the images again and the docx can converted. So what do you think the problem is ?

Comment: Here https://github.com/ConvertAPI/convertapi-php/blob/master/lib/ConvertApi/ConvertApi.php you can find all execution timeouts which can be adjusted accordingly. You can adjust it by changing ConvertApi::$connectTimeout value.